# Change of variable for differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable

Given the following differential equation
\begin{equation}
-y(\zeta) \left(\frac{d^2 y(\zeta)^{-1}}{d \zeta^2}+2 j c \frac{d y(\zeta)^{-1}}{d \zeta}\right)+c^2 (1+y(\zeta)^{2})=\\
\frac{y''(\zeta)}{y(\zeta)}-\frac{2 y'(\zeta)^2}{y(\zeta)^2}+\frac{2 c j y'(\zeta)}{y(\zeta)}+c^2 y(\zeta)^2+c^2=f(\zeta)
\end{equation}
Is there a change of variables that allows the differential equation to be transformed into the following form? In the above equation c is a constant, while $j=\sqrt{-1}$.
\begin{equation}
 -\frac{1}{2 a(\zeta)}\left(\frac{d^2 a(\zeta)}{d \zeta^2}-\frac{1}{2 a(\zeta)}\left(\frac{d a(\zeta)}{d \zeta}\right)^2 \right)+\frac{c}{a(\zeta)^2}=f(\zeta)
\end{equation}
If this variable change exists, how is it possible to find it?

A first attempt is to use a generic change of variables to identify the function $F$ such that
$a(\zeta)=F(y(\zeta))$. Proceeding in this way it is possible to transform the second equation
in the following way
\begin{equation}
-y''(\zeta)\frac{F'(y(\zeta))}{2 F(y(\zeta))}+y'(\zeta)^2 \left(\frac{F'(y(\zeta))^2}{4 F(y(\zeta))^2}-\frac{F''(y(\zeta))}{2 F(y(\zeta))}\right)+\frac{c}{F(y(\zeta))^2}=f(\zeta)
\end{equation}
The initial problem then reduces to identifying the function $F$ such that the first and the third equations are equal.
However, as of this point, I have no idea how to proceed. Also, I am not sure that changing variables $a(\zeta)=F(y(\zeta))$ is enough to solve the problem. As pointed out by Sal the change of variables for the independent variable $\zeta$ cannot help us to solve the problem.

As an example we consider the change of variables $a(\zeta)=y(\zeta)^{-2}$. This change of variables is not correct in fact the second equation becomes:
\begin{equation}
\frac{y''(\zeta)}{y(\zeta)}-\frac{2 y'(\zeta)^2}{y(\zeta)^2}+c y(\zeta)^4=f(\zeta)
\end{equation}
which is different from the first equation although two terms are common to both equations.

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac{dy(\zeta)^{-1}}{d\zeta}$?

Comment: I mean the first derivative of $\frac{1}{y(\zeta)}$

Comment: The equation involving $F$ has no $y'$ term, while the first equation does. Since $F$ is presumed to be only a function of $y$ they can't be equal. Changing $\zeta \to G(\zeta)$ also can't be the solution because the RHS of both equations is the same $f(\zeta)$. You could consider a more general transformation $F=F(y,\zeta)$ or $F(y,y')$ etc... Is there any reason to think the transformation is possible?

Comment: Sal, first of all thank you very much. I fully agree on the fact that changing $\zeta \to G(\zeta)$ can't be the solution. As your first sentence I don't understand what do you mean when writing "while the first equation does". F has no $y'$ term, ok but there is a first derivative in the second equation.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417534/change-of-variable-for-differential-equations